# Gridworld Fill Grid

Tags: java, computer-science, gridworld

Having trouble filling the grid. Everytime I do it I get a stackoverflow error. Here is my current code :

```
public void removeSelfFromGrid() {
    Grid<Actor> grid = getGrid();
    int rows = grid.getNumRows();
    int cols = grid.getNumCols();
    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<cols; j++) {
            Location loc = new Location(i, j);
            laugh = new CKiller();
            laugh.putSelfInGrid(grid, loc);
        }   
    }    
}
```

and here is the constructor if needed

```
public CKiller()
 {
    Color c = null;
    setColor(c);
    getGrid();
    getLocation();
    location = new ArrayList<Location>();
    location.add(getLocation());
    setDirection(direction);
 }
```

And here is the error (part of it, too big to post all. it's just those 2 statements repeated):

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at info.gridworld.actor.Actor.putSelfInGrid(Actor.java:123)
at CKiller.removeSelfFromGrid(CKiller.java:120)
```

It's saying this is the problem

```
laugh.putSelfInGrid(grid, loc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following:

-Are you defining `laugh` prior to the removeSelfFromGrid() method call? It doesn't have a type specified before it.

-Should the variable `location` not be an ArrayList? It might be a Location object.

-Is the int `direction` defined already?

-Why are you calling getGrid() and getLocation()? They aren't doing anything beneficial.

-Does CKiller inherit the putSelfInGrid() method from the Actor class?

Please include the full code of the CKiller class as well as the main class that contains removeSelfFromGrid().

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you overrode the `removeSelfFromGrid()` method. You should have created a new method, such as `fillGrid()`.

When an actor calls `putSelfInGrid()`, if there is currently another actor in that `Location` it calls `removeSelfFromGrid()`, which you overrode to fill every `Location` on the `Grid` with an actor. If there are any other actors on the grid they will then call `removeSelfFromGrid()`, which leads to again filling the grid, etc.

Just fix the code in `removeSelfFromGrid()`, put it in a new method and restore the previous code, and you should be good.